# Using binlog format row, is there any possibility to omit the statement text itself, and only having the binary part?

Tags: mariadb, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I have set the following in MariaDB:

```
binlog-format=row 
binlog_row_image=MINIMAL # probably out of topic
log_bin_compress # probably out of topic
```

When I use mysqlbinlog I see both the

```
#Q> INSERT INTO mydb.mytable ...
```

and the

```
BINLOG '
WGrTYx...
```

lines.

**Question**

Is there any possibility to omit the statement text itself, and only having the binary part in the binlog?

(or fooled I myself with mysqlbinlog output, and in the original binlog file there is no redundancy?)

Comment: Please clarify what problem you are trying to solve. Are you concerned about the size of the binlogs, or the amount of I/O to write them, as in your other question on Stack Overflow? Or another reason?

Comment: You said you are using MariaDB, not MySQL, so I removed the mysql tag. MariaDB is not MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed significantly since then. They are not compatible anymore, and we should treat them as wholly different products.

Comment: Many thx, for clarify. Indeed, the size, and the related I/O is the concern.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly binlog_annotate_row_events = 0 (default 1) is what you are looking for:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#binlog_annotate_row_events

Comment: many thx. I am going to test it, then back with the result...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [--raw](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_raw) and see it hides the SQL text.

### [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_raw) says

> By default, mysqlbinlog reads binary log files and writes events in text format. ***The [--raw](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_raw) option tells mysqlbinlog to write them in their original binary format. Its use requires that [--read-from-remote-server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_read-from-remote-server) also be used because the files are requested from a server***. mysqlbinlog writes one output file for each file read from the server. The [--raw](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_raw) option can be used to make a backup of a server's binary log. With the [--stop-never](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_stop-never) option, the backup is “live” because mysqlbinlog stays connected to the server. By default, output files are written in the current directory with the same names as the original log files. Output file names can be modified using the [--result-file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_result-file) option. For more information, see Section 4.6.9.3, “Using mysqlbinlog to Back Up Binary Log Files”.

### [MariaDB Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlbinlog-options/) says

> Requires -R. Output raw binlog data instead of SQL statements. Output files named after server logs. (since MariaDB 10.2)

### Notes on MariaDB

- -R is [--read-from-remote-server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_read-from-remote-server)
- From MariaDB 10.4.6, mariadb-binlog is a symlink to mysqlbinlog.
- From MariaDB 10.5.2, mariadb-binlog is the name of the tool, with mysqlbinlog a symlink .

Comment: Many thx for your answer. I do not care about mysqlbinlog output size, my only concern is the binlog size itself. Seeing mysqlbinlo capable to fecontruct the whole SQL statement from a binlog, which was configured to row format (not statement format) I concluded this information must there in binlog. Because in the actual use case I do not need that, I wondering, if it is redundant, is there a way to not include it (in binlog)